# Может ли класс - наследник EditText получить через конструктор дополнительный параметр?

Tags: android, android-edittext

есть задумка заставить EditText автоматически воздейстdовать на главное меню, путем изменения дополнительных параметров в конструкторе. Создаю класс наследник SupEditText, включаю в конструктор дополнительный int id, но приложение вылетает.

Как пример

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        SupEditText tv = new SupEditText(this, null, 50);
        tv = (SupEditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
}
```

и новый класс

```
public class SupEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{



    public SupEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int id) {
        super(context, attrs);
        String string = String.valueOf(id);
        Toast.makeText(context, "12345", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Убрав int id (и все к нему относящееся), все запускается.
Пожалуйста просветите в чем здесь дело! Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы вписали вью в разметку, то обязаны объявить конструктор с двумя параметрами:
`(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`
именно его использует `LayoutInflater` и соответственно вы не можете использовать дополнительные параметры.
Вместо этого вы можете добавить атрибут для этой вью, задать ему значение в разметке и получить в конструкторе. И/или сделать просто сеттер и выставлять его отдельно.
Конструкторы с дополнительными параметрами можно использовать только в коде - и создать экземпляр, и добавить его в контейнер.